# "Error in srv_paramset." upon execution of sp_OAGetProperty

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to get node value of `type` node. It must return the `string` "my_type" , but an empty string is returned.

```
declare @v_msg int
DECLARE @loadXML_result INT
declare @v_line varchar(4000)
declare @nodelist int
DECLARE @node      INT   
DECLARE @childnode INT
DECLARE @CHILDNODE_nodevalue VARCHAR(MAX)

set @v_line = 
'<message>
<type>my_type</type>
</message>';

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0',@v_msg OUTPUT
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @v_msg,'loadXML',@loadXML_result OUTPUT,@v_line

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @v_msg,'getElementsByTagName',@nodelist OUTPUT,'type'
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @nodelist,'Item',@node OUTPUT,0
EXECUTE sp_OAGetProperty @node,'firstChild',@childnode OUTPUT
print concat('child_node ',@childnode)
EXECUTE sp_OAGetProperty @childnode,'nodeValue',@CHILDNODE_nodevalue OUTPUT

print concat ('CHILDNODE_nodevalue ',@CHILDNODE_nodevalue)
```

Further check on the status of execution of `sp_OAGetProperty` shows that there was error :

```
DECLARE @hr INT
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @node,'Text',@CHILDNODE_nodevalue OUTPUT

--Check status of the previous execution of sp_OAGetProperty
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @node
```

Output of `EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @node` above :

[image]

Comment: Can't you just use [`XML` data type + `nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Possible Alternative :**

If you can afford to use `XML` data type and `nodes()` function, you can try this way :

```
declare @v_line XML, @CHILDNODE_nodevalue VARCHAR(MAX)
set @v_line = 
'<message>
<type>my_type</type>
</message>';

select @CHILDNODE_nodevalue = x.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(max)') 
from @v_line.nodes('//type') as T(x)

print @CHILDNODE_nodevalue
```

**Solution :**

Regarding the original problem, I'm not actually familiar with SQL Server's OLE automation at all. But a little research shows that `sp_OAGetProperty` somehow isn't compatible with `VARCHAR(MAX)` data type as output variable. Changing output variable data type -`@CHILDNODE_nodevalue` for this case- to a fixed length `VARCHAR` immediately solve the problem for me. No more changes to the original query needed.

You can also save several `EXECUTE sp_` lines by using MSXML's `SelectSingleNode()` instead of `getElementsByTagName()` for this particular task :

```
declare @v_msg int
DECLARE @loadXML_result INT
declare @v_line varchar(4000)
DECLARE @node      INT   
DECLARE @CHILDNODE_nodevalue VARCHAR(1000)
                           --^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
                           --try not to use VARCHAR(MAX)

set @v_line = 
'<message>
<type>my_type</type>
</message>';

EXECUTE sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0',@v_msg OUTPUT
EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @v_msg,'loadXML',@loadXML_result OUTPUT,@v_line

EXECUTE sp_OAMethod @v_msg,'SelectSingleNode',@node OUTPUT,'//type'
EXECUTE sp_OAGetProperty @node,'Text',@CHILDNODE_nodevalue OUTPUT

print concat('CHILDNODE_nodevalue ',@CHILDNODE_nodevalue)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but all project uses OLE-objects for XML and if I implement your solution, almost all code will be rewrite. My example is a little part of project and it is gathered from different procedures

Comment: @WalentynaJuszkiewicz You can always use `sp_OAGetErrorInfo` to check status of previous OLE automation procedure execution for debugging purpose

Comment: har07, thank you very much for your answer! It's really helpful. I've changed varchar(max) to varchar(8000) and it works now! Great! thank you!

Comment: @WalentynaJuszkiewicz I've tried to google the error message and can't find anything relevant. So I think this is the right place to document the solution. Hope you don't mind with the edit I made to the question! Also thanks for confirming that it works for you too!

Comment: Umm.. just found some links saying that the limit is know to be 8000 bytes (`varchar(8000)`), so umm.. at least nothing relevant here in StackOverlow :p

Comment: Thank you @WalentynaJuszkiewicz. Your comment about changing varchar(max) to varchar(8000) really helped me.